# compressing multiple files using zip command

Tags: macos, zip

I am trying to compress multiple video files using the "zip" command on a Mac box running OS X 10.5.8. I have 515 video files that are approximately 572 MB each. I want to compress/add each file to an archive called "2014-08.zip" and then delete the file immediately afterwards to save disk space. I tried doing this by moving all 515 of the files into a separate directory, cd'ing into that directory and running the following commands:

for file in *
do
zip -m 2014-08.zip $file
done

Unfortunately, this only worked for the first 4 files. Once it got to file #5, it began spitting out errors complaining about "invalid arguments."

Here's a snapshot of my terminal session:

```
$ for file in *
> do
> zip -m 2014-08.zip $file
> done
  adding: capture3_CH-01-0312.avi (deflated 31%)
  adding: capture3_CH-01-0313.avi (deflated 26%)
  adding: capture3_CH-01-0314.avi (deflated 26%)
  adding: capture3_CH-01-0315.avi (deflated 27%)
  adding: capture3_CH-01-0316.avi
zip I/O error: Invalid argument

zip error: Input file read failure (was zipping capture3_CH-01-0316.avi)

  adding: capture3_CH-01-0317.avi
zip I/O error: Invalid argument

zip error: Input file read failure (was zipping capture3_CH-01-0317.avi)
```

At this point, I terminated the process using ctrl+c. Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there a way to get around this bug?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Try putting `$file` in double qotes, like this `"$file"`, in case there is a space in a filename...

Comment: I agree that is generally good practice, however none of my files contain any spaces in their filenames, so that can't be what's causing this...

Comment: Ok, are you maybe on Windows using Cygwin or somesuch? If you are using a FAT32 filesystem, it has a 2GB limit on filesize and you are getting stuck on the 5th file of 500MB... Or maybe some other filesystem without `largefiles` enabled.

Comment: just FYI, I figured out what was causing this. OSX apparently comes with a very dated version of "zip" that does not support large archives. The only solution I could find is to upgrade to a newer version of zip.